# in cmake how do I apply -std=c++11 flag for C++ code, but not for C code in the same directory

Tags: cmake

In a project with a mixture of C++ and C code in one directory, I need the -std=c++11 flag to apply for the C++ code, but not the C code. (Because that causes an error on MacOS.)

Currently I do this:

```
add_compile_options( -std=c++11 )
```

However, there don't seem to be any options on the add_compile_options() function to allow me to specify that these flags should only be used for C++ files.

In autotools this would be achieved by setting CXXFLAGS for C++ and CFLAGS for C code. Is there some way to do the same in CMake?

Comment: https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/

Craig Scott actually has a blog post addressing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `add_compile_options` for anything, ever! In the worst case, you can use `target_compile_options`, but for setting the language standard, CMake has special support that should always be preferred.

For the target you want to compile as C++11, simply write:

```
target_compile_features(my_target PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
```

Comment: Don't use add_compile_options ever? Then why is it present in CMake?

Comment: Legacy, basically. The whole set of directory commands should not be used in new code. Always use the `target_*` commands when one is available.

Comment: Commands like `add_compile_options` are global. Using them makes things harder to use and mantain both for you, and for your users (if you're a library author). If you have the time, check [this](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/intro/dodonot.html) out - it has some great advice for how to write better CMake files.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `target_compile_features` in other answer, if not, use `set_property` as also presented in other answer. Still, you can pass `compile_options` specifically to C++ compiler with generator expression:

```
# prefer other answers to it
add_compile_options(
     $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-std=c++11>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. Note you must specify the required property. And I like to disable extensions to not rely on any compiler specific flags.

```
set_target_properties(myTarget
    PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 11
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
        CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using

```
# Setting your C++ standard.
set_property(TARGET your_target PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
# Setting your C standard.
set_property(TARGET your_target PROPERTY C_STANDARD 11)
```

Of course the standard number has to be a supported version number:

- For C++ this includes: 98, 11, 14, 17, 20 and 23.
- For C this includes: 90, 99 and 11.

You do not have to use both of them. You can thus ask CMake to use C++11 while still using the default C standard.

Comment: Please note, I did not test it, but it should be working.

Comment: Suggestion use set_target_properties instead

Comment: This answer doesn't consider the following properties: [CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html?highlight=cxx_standard_required). It's also good practice to disable [CXX_EXTENSIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_EXTENSIONS.html?highlight=cxx_extensions)